# How do I receive get data send by client without reloading

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a bit of a newbie in the world of express and node.
I'm sending some dummy data with jquery to the server

```
var data = { key1: '2938', key2: '29993' };
$.get( "/receiver", function( data ) {alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );})
```

and on server side I want to use the received data

```
app.get('/receiver', function(request, response) {
var id = request.data;
response.end("I have received the ID: " + id);
console.log(request.data);
});
```

How do I do this the proper way?

thanks!

Comment: how you're currently doing it is correct.  Post what you want to do with the data after this, and we can advise further :)

Comment: Thanks @Fishbowl ! Basically the problem I'm having is I don't know how to retrieve the key1 and key2 properties... If I write console.log(request.data.key1); I get an error.

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a POST in this instance, as your processing is happening on the server side (i.e. you're posting your data to the server, rather than getting data from it using a key).  In that case, you'd want to use a `$.post(...` on the client side, and use the syntax `request.body` on the server-side to retrieve the data

Comment: @Fishbowl Can you elaborate a bit why POST instead of GET. Not sure I understand the difference.

Comment: A GET would imply that you're trying to pull raw data from the server and process it on the client-side.  A POST would be pushing the raw data to the server, processing it, and returning the result. - At least, that's how I use GET and POST, but i'm not claiming to be a HTTP expert.  I'm sure there are others around here who could give more concise answers